# How to sheet link in excel cell with pandas

Tags: pandas, excel, openpyxl

I'm scraping a workbook with a bunch of sheets that I want to access one by one (With pandas). I want to acces each worksheet by a sheet link that lies in cells in an "overview sheet". In excel you just click the cell with the sheet link, and it gets you to the right worksheet instantly, however I can't find any python function in pandas nor in openpyxl that can accesses this link.

I have tried:

```
print(sheet1.cell(row=9, column=2).hyperlink.target)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. The link is not written in the cell per se, it's more of a formatting, it seems.

[image: Here is the cell with the link]

[image: And down here is the corresponding worksheet]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you are looking for the [`location`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.hyperlink.html?highlight=location#openpyxl.worksheet.hyperlink.Hyperlink.location) of the hyperlinks :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("file.xlsx")

sheet_names = []
for cell in wb["Overview"]["B"]:
    if (hl:=cell.hyperlink):
        sheet_names.append(hl.location.split("!")[0])
```

You can then make dataframes of those sheets with openpyxl or with [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) / `sheet_name`.

Output :

```
print(sheet_names) # ['Sheet2', 'Sheet3']
```

Used input (*file.xlsx*) :

[image]

Comment: It will be good to realize that this will cause `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'`, when the list of hyperlinks also includes links to websites, or a new document. This is because such *external* links will have `location=None`, and the actual target as a string assigned to the `target` attribute. Indeed, this is doubtlessly the source of the OP's confusion. So, you might want to consider squeezing in a `if hl.location:` as well to avoid such a failure.

Comment: That makes total sense, guess I missed that one! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The first time I've seen the walrus operator used! Not enough to convince me it was a good idea. ;-)